# How to incorporate .dll files into a self-contained application on Windows

Tags: windows, dll

I am on Windows 10, and I developed an application with graphical user interface, which uses some external libraries. The application is in C++ and it uses some .lib library files, such as the Gnu Scienfitc Library

```
C:\gsl-master\lib\x64\Debug\gsl.lib
```

When I build the app with Visual Studio, it generates an executable .exe, which runs.
However, if I copy this .exe to another computer and launch it, it complains with 'The code execution cannot proceed because MSCCPI40D.dll was not found'.

- How can I create a self-contained app package that contains all the .dll files that it needs?
- How can I incorporate  into this package also the .lib files needed by the applications such as gsl.lib?

Thanks

Comment: use static, not dynamic linking

Comment: static linking with a lib file.  Most open source libraries include build instructions and a project / solution / makefile that allows for both static (lib) and dynamic (dll) builds.

Comment: So if I use static linking the .exe file will be self-sufficient and it will run without any other library file ?

Comment: You'll remove the need for each DLL that you replace with a statically-linked library.

Comment: [IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#other-considerations)